# Apply Temporary Skill Shortage visa while applying for permanent resident visa to Australia

Tags: australia

I am holding a Business Visitor (subclass 600) with me now for Australia. I have planned to apply for permanent residency.

If my employer ask me to apply for a Temporary Skill Shortage (subclass 482) visa while I have applied for my PR visa, what would happen? Can I apply for another type of Visa while a Visa is in progress.

Also could I still use my visitor visa to travel when the PR or TSS visa applied and  in progress?

Comment: Do you mean TSS visa? That is what [replaced the 457](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/work/457-abolition-replacement).

Comment: Yes exactly, I meant TSS visa..

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not yet employed in Australia, I presume you are applying for permanent residence via the [Skilled Independent (subclass 189) visa](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/189-).  If so, the answer is easy: **you can apply for a 189 visa at any time, whether or not you are in Australia**.  You can also travel to/from Australia while a 189 or TSS/482 visa application is pending.

> *Location*
>
> You can be in or outside Australia when you submit your EOI.

A couple of catches:

- You can't apply for a 189 directly, you can only submit an Expression of Interest (EOI) that the government may or may not get back to you about.  Waiting up to a year for them to do so is normal.
- If you apply for any Australian visa (including TSS/482) *and are refused*, you may be disqualified from applying for a 189.

Comment: Thank you for the catches. But, I intended to know is, could I apply for TSS while I have applied for 189 Visa (could be in any status, like, have Submitted my EOI and waiting for a response Or Received a response and visa is in progress OR any status).